# Neo4j: How to lock the entire database

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

In mysql, you can lock the entire database by issuing:
`FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;`

To unlock a mysql database, issue the following:
`UNLOCK TABLES;`

Are there two such commands for neo4j (lock and unlock the entire database)? If not, is there some clever steps to take in order to achieve a database-wide lock/unlock?

[Neo4j Transactions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/transactions.html):
Locks are acquired at the Node and Relationship level.

[Neo4j does NOT lock during a backup](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/operations-backup.html):

> A full backup copies the database files without acquiring any locks

Comment: Can I ask what your use case is for this?

Comment: I have a mysql database and a neo4j database. An update to either *could* invoke an update to the other. I want to backup both databases. My thinking would be to lock both, kick off backups on both, unlock both.

Answer (score 0):

there is an option in neo4j.settings file where you can make the db read-only, but this requires a restart of the instance. i'm not aware of any pragmatic way of how to lock and unlock it on the go.